# prefix "Use " being added to agent action causing InvalidTool to be invoked again and again

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

I have added the tools named `A_tool`, `default_tool` to a `ZeroShotAgent`.

The output from one of the execution looks like:

```
Thought: We need to use the A_tool.
Action: Use A_tool
Observation: Use A_tool is not a valid tool, try another one.
Thought:We need to use the default_tool since A_tool is not a valid tool.
    
Action: Use default_tool
Action Input: None
Observation: Use default_tool is not a valid tool, try another one.
I am not sure why the prefix Use  is getting added to Action.....ideally action should be just the name of the tool [A_tool, default_tool]
```

This is causing `InvalidTool` is being invoked again and again.

What can i do to fix this issue?

I tried changing the description of my tools to resolve the issue and altering the temperature for the LLM model that I am invoking.

Comment: Raise an issue for the same in langchain framework codebase also https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/8407